# I want to create another cylinder simulation in the left side in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

i want to simulate another piston on the left side like in this picture.[There are 2 pistons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWyqq.png).

However, the original code only has 1 piston on the right. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PidR.png).

I want to know how do i create another one and simulate it?
This is the MATLAB code:

```
B = VideoWriter('transition');
B.Quality=100;
B.FrameRate=120;
open(B);
k=figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
c=1;

for i=1:1:size(alpha,1)
      
    
subplot(3,2,2)
    plot(alpha(1:i),x(1:i)), grid, title('distance travel of the linkage'), xlabel('crank rotation [rad]'), ylabel('[m]'),axis([0 6 0 90])
subplot(3,2,4)
    plot(alpha(1:i),d_x(1:i)), grid, title('Velocity of linkage'), xlabel('crank rotation [rad]'), ylabel('[m/s]'),axis([0 6 -30000 30000])
subplot(3,2,6)
    plot(alpha(1:i),d2_x(1:i)), grid, title('Accelerations of linkage'), xlabel('crank rotation [rad]'), ylabel('m/s^2'),axis([0 6 -1.5*10^7 2.5*10^7])
    subplot(3,2,[1,3,5])
    plot([0 r*cos(alpha(i))],[0 r*sin(alpha(i))],'LineWidth',3,'Color','k') 
    grid on
    hold on
    axis([-250 250 -250 250])
    plot([0],[0],'.','MarkerSize',10,'Color','r')
    plot([r*cos(alpha(i))],[r*sin(alpha(i))],'.','MarkerSize',30,'Color','r')
    rectangle('position',[r*cos(alpha(i))+l*cos(beta(i))-20*cos(pi/4) -20*sin(pi/4) 2*20*cos(pi/4) 2*20*sin(pi/4)],'FaceColor',[0.6 0.6 0.6],'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1,'Curvature',0.2)
    plot([r*cos(alpha(i)) r*cos(alpha(i))+l*cos(beta(i))],[r*sin(alpha(i)) 0],'LineWidth',3,'Color','k')
    plot([r*cos(alpha(i))],[r*sin(alpha(i))],'.','MarkerSize',30,'Color','r')
    plot([r*cos(alpha(i))+l*cos(beta(i))],[0],'.','MarkerSize',30,'Color','r')
    
    hold off
    
    vid(c)=getframe(k);
    writeVideo(B,vid(c))
    c=c+1;
end

close(k);
close(B);
```

I want a code to create another piston on the right and simulate it

Comment: What have you tried? You got one piston drawn, what are you having trouble with to get the other?

Comment: I want another piston  on the opposite side, idk if you can help me w ith that?

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but you appear to have all the tools you need to do it. If you understand the equations for the crank position and connecting rod, you understand how to make a plot, then I don't know what's stopping you from creating another set of equations for the other piston and adding that to your plot.

Comment: yeah, I created another piston on the other side, but I cannot connect it to the crank of the first piston. Also, idk why my second piston travel faster than my first one...